MS Access pass-through query to SQL Server stored procedure returns records for admin but not standard user
I have an MS Access database application that uses pass-through queries to run stored procedures.
One of then is setup to return the results of a stored procedure, and it works perfectly as long as I am (a SQL admin) connected to SQL Server via a trusted connection.
But, when I test it with a standard user with execution rights to the procedure, the procedure runs and does what it is supposed to do, but Access returns error 3325 saying it did not return any results.
I am using AD Security groups to give SQL permissions and to connect using trusted connections, to the users, and I have given execution rights for the procedures to the users in the group. The group also has data read and data write permissions to the database.
So, what am I missing?

Microsoft Access for Microsoft 365
SQL Server 2017

Thank you

Does the SP work for users if they use a SQL client like SSMS (or if you don't want to install that, perhaps HeidiSQL portable)? You may get more descriptive error messages here.

I was going to try that today. I'll get back to you.
